At which point in a Grails app's filter chain does the GrailsWebRequest get fully initialized?
I am attempting to build a filter in a Grails 6 app that requires access to a fully initialized GrailsWebRequest that includes the controller name and action for the current request. I expected that if I placed my filter AFTER the GrailsWebRequestFilter that calling WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest() in my filter would provide me with a GrailsWebRequest instance that includes the controllerName and actionName.
However, I am experiencing that an instance is available but it does not include controllerName and actionName, both fields are null. They are available in my Controller action. Is there another filter responsible for injecting these values into the request instance later down the chain I am missing?

Grails has a concept of interceptors (https://docs.grails.org/6.2.0/guide/single.html#interceptors) that allows you to have code before / after any controller call.  Is there a reason you need a filter over using the builtin mechanism?

I am looking to have the filter execute ahead of other spring filters and it was my understanding Interceptors couldn't be placed outside of a grails app.

In the ControllersGrailsPlugin you can see that the grails web request filter has an order of: OrderedFilter.REQUEST_WRAPPER_FILTER_MAX_ORDER + 30
Try adding a filter with an order +31 and then accessing the web request?
Also, it looks like Grails Interceptors are just Spring's HandlerInterceptor so it may be possible to create an interceptor that works both in Grails & Spring by implementing that interface and registering it with Grails.

This is precisely the approach I tried in my original approach, it turns out that the grails web request filter does not initialize the controller name or action for the request.

In Grails 6, instead of using filters (which are deprecated), you can use standalone interceptors to access the controllerName and actionName from the GrailsWebRequest. Interceptors are executed at the right point in the request lifecycle, ensuring that controllerName and actionName are available.
Here's how you can implement this:

Create an Interceptor - you can create an interceptor using the Grails CLI:

grails create-interceptor MyInterceptor


In your interceptor, the before method will have access to fully initialized GrailsWebRequest, including the controllerName and actionName.

class MyInterceptor {

    MyInterceptor() {
        // Optionally match specific controllers or actions
        matchAll()
    }

    boolean before() {
        def grailsWebRequest = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
        println "Controller: ${grailsWebRequest.controllerName}"  // Should be populated
        println "Action: ${grailsWebRequest.actionName}"          // Should be populated
        return true  // Continue execution
    }

    boolean after() { true }

    void afterView() {
        // No-op
    }
}


Interceptors in Grails can be ordered to control when they are executed in the request lifecycle. If you need this interceptor to run after others, you can configure its order:

class MyInterceptor {

    int order = LOWEST_PRECEDENCE  // Ensures it runs later in the chain

    MyInterceptor() {
        matchAll()  // Matches all controllers and actions
    }

    boolean before() {
        def grailsWebRequest = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
        println "Controller: ${grailsWebRequest.controllerName}"
        println "Action: ${grailsWebRequest.actionName}"
        return true
    }

    boolean after() { true }

    void afterView() {}
}

By using interceptor, you ensure that the controllerName and actionName are correctly initialized and accessible before any action is executed.
I'd recommend reading Grails Documentation for more information.

Thanks for the thoughtful response. How can I execute a Grails Interceptor before a spring filter, such as one setup by the grails spring security plugin or similar?

When is GrailsWebRequest intalized in a grails 5 application?

So after much experimentation the best approach I could come up with, since I am unable to use a grails interceptor, was to use UrlMappingsHolder.matchAll to obtain a UrlMappingInfo that has the controller name and action.
It turns out that UrlMappingInfo.configure(GrailsWebRequest webRequest) injects the controller name and action onto a GrailsWebRequest, and this is not done in a filter, such as GrailsWebRequestFilter but rather in a spring HandlerAdapter such as UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter right before invoking the controller.
